# Simple aggregate $lookup function returns undefined mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm using keystone.js CMS with node.

I'm unable to get this aggregate function to work at all. I've whittled it down to this bare-bones $lookup, and all I get is undefined. I've seen other similar questions, but they were more complex with explanations that don't solve my problem:

```
keystone.list('User').model.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'follows',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'follower',
                as: 'follows'
            }
        }
    ]).exec(function(err, followers) {
        console.log(followers);
    });
```

Here is the error:

```
MongoError: The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: post the error you're receiving.

Comment: @Geoffroy I'm not receiving an error, just returning 'undefined' to the console.

Comment: In `function(err, followers)`, what do you have in `err` ?

Comment: i feel like your using the wrong collection name or database, if theres no error aggregate returns an empty array.

Comment: @Geoffroy I added the error to my question, you are correct. It says 'The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument.'